# regex101 Conditional statement is always else

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using http://www.regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/ to learn regex

regex101's Quick reference shows

**Conditional statement:** `(?(...)|)`

> If the given pattern matches, matches the pattern before the vertical bar. Otherwise, matches the pattern after the vertical bar.

I can't get it to work at all

```
/(^(?!no)if|else)/gm
```

no if **else**

yes if **else**

looks like its broken

```
/(?:(yes)true|false)/g
```

yes true **false**

I need to return a single match using `string.match` so I stay compatible with a third party. I don't have the option to do anything with the results myself so I won't be able to do multiple regex nor filter results with javascript. what I would like to achive is a regex that asks for

if the sentence starts with the word '`name`' or the sentence contains '`.classX`' then return nothing else return '`.classA`'

returning eather `[""]` or `[".classA "]`

Is this possible at all or am I completly waisting my time?

Comment: Well, you are not following the syntax. As you quoted, the pattern is `(?(test)true|false)`. You are either introducing characters between `?(` (such as `(?:(` or you complete change the parenthesis placement (`(?!no)`). However, I don't think JS supports conditionals anyway, so there is no need to pursue that road.

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html for a detailed explanation of conditionals.

Comment: `/((?yes)true|false)/` invalid group structure error on regex101

Comment: JavaScript does not support regex conditional statements, as Felix stated.

Comment: @BenMuircroft: What  Fabrício said. However,  `((?yes)true|false)` is *still* incorrect. If any, it should be `(?(yes)true|false)`

Comment: Then why dose SO point me to regex101 who list that they do work????

Comment: @BenMuircroft: Could it be that you selected pcre(php) as language in https://regex101.com/? The quick reference doesn't list conditionals for JavaScript.

Comment: I did, wow that is a day In my life im never getting back. Can someone please answer as this is not supported and I will accept.

Comment: There is probably a workaround to do it without to use a conditional statement. I suggest you to add examples string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support the full spectrum of regular expression features, which is why your conditionals are not working.

Take a look at the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for a complete list of supported features.

Answer (score 0):

While regex is indeed very powerful, I'd recommend that you delegate the conditionals to javascript.

So for your example at the end of your post, you would just create a pattern to match "name" or ".classX", and if `match()` returns true, you return "" in javascript. Else, return ".classA".

Comment: I can't accept this mate, It's in the question that I am unable to filter my results with js. thanks all the same

Comment: Sorry, didn't really understand what you meant until I read it a few more times. What's preventing you from "filtering" with javascript? How are you able to use javascript in the first place?

Comment: I use javascript to send the regex to a third party then they do what they want... I will have to do this another way. never mind